# Matter-antimatter asymmetry problem

Tags: antimatter, baryogenesis

As we know that matter-antimatter asymmetry is one of unsolved problems in physics. One possible solution to this problem is given as baryogenesis which produce asymmetry in rate of creation between matter and antimatter particles. But doesn't alternate solution like "different regions of space with different type of particles " holds more ground..

Means in one region matter particle dominates (the region we live ) and another region anti matter particle will dominate. When particle-antiparticle pair created from energy (at that energy is so much high that particle- antiparticle pair could be created from energy according to $E=mc^2$) before they meet and annihilate with each other they also has equal chance of meeting with same type of particle in neighborhood, because after some time of big bang the four force were united and gravity was as powerful as remaining three forces. So now in 50% of all pairs destroyed by annihilation and other 50% clumps together with same type of particle means matter with matter and antimatter with antimatter and then inflationary epoch throw these clumps from each other at very large distance so that they can not meet each other and have chance of annihilation. And we now can not see these regions because of accelerated expansion of universe because of dark energy.

Doesn't this hypothesis is more or at least equally valid with baryogeneis hypothesis.

Comment: As long as you say "And we can not see it" _any_ hypothesis is valid, but it's not scientific unless you can propose an experiment that would show evidence of this.

Comment: Various duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41483/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26397/ http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11652/

Answer (score 1):

No. The reason is very simple: If there was such an anti-matter universe, we would see very strong lines in the cosmic background radiation related to the particle masses. Those lines would come from annihilation processes like
$$ e^+ e^- \rightarrow \gamma + \gamma $$

If you suggest that the anti-world is too far away to produce such a signal, I'm sorry but all I can say is that inflation doesn't work that way.

Comment: But can't we do following at least theoretically:  1) Find out how particle and anti particle behave under the influence of four forces by applying each force one by one with first particle and then anti particle.2)Then find out what happen to this pair of particle- antiparticle pair under four force on by one and then.3)Take one special case of say 100 pairs of this particle-antiparticle pairs in influence of those four forces with same strength and given rate of expanding of space with them and find out how those pairs reacts . This way we can check this alternate scenario...I guess

Comment: We do know how particles and antiparticles interact with the different forces. Their charges are reversed, i.e. they will attract each other. When we look at what happens to a particle-antiparticle pair we see that they will anihilate each other similarly to what I have shown.